# UICollectionView didselectitematindexpath delegate?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

UICollectionView how to achieve didselectitematindexpath，when I selected one item, give a  flag the Item,  and it will be  push to the next ViewController at the same time.When  pop back the ViewController, how can I  identify the selected(pre-seclect) Item, how to retain the item's flag?
How to come true above description？

Comment: You make a `currentSelectedIndex` global variable and save it in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, and get it back in `viewWillAppear` when you pop back.

Comment: Sorry I want to tincolor the Item seclected. How to insue only one item was seclected(tincolor)?

Comment: I believe only one item can be selected.

Comment: I was not understand your method(You make a currentSelectedIndex global variable and save it in didSelectItemAtIndexPath, and get it back in viewWillAppear when you pop back).

Comment: Please go through this link http://www.objc.io/issue-12/collectionview-animations.html

Comment: I was not understand your method(You make a currentSelectedIndex global variable and save it in didSelectItemAtIndexPath, and get it back in viewWillAppear when you pop back). I want to come true Only one Item was(tincolor), when pop back, the tincolor item was Just seclected item, but I found that two item was tincolor(include pre-selectitem), how to recover the pre-seclectedItem.I mean only one item was tincolor In UI

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViewController has a property `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`, as default its value is YES, so in `viewWillAppear:`, UICollectionViewController will set all the selected item to unselect.
So I guess this is what you need.

Also you could use `[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]` to get all the selected item's indexPath in `viewWillAppear:` before you call `[super viewWillAppear:]`.